# Firebase Storage Project Level Permissions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I store files in Firebase Storage as follows:

```
/{projectId}/{file}
```

Users have different permissions based on the `projectId`, and can easily have some level of permissions on tens (or even hundreds) of projects. For each project, he or she is assigned a role, which determines what operations are permitted.

I have these roles stored in Firestore by the user, but they are inaccessible in the Firebase Storage security rules.

Furthermore, setting custom claims with all project roles for each user will easily exceed the 1000 byte limit for custom claims. Is there any way to lookup permissions at the time of file access, i.e., update, delete, read/download?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to access documents in Firestore from security rules defined for Storage.  Custom claims is the only common permissions system shared between the two products.

Consider routing access through Cloud Functions if you need more a more flexible logic, either before or after the fact.

Please feel free to [file a feature request with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

Comment: How could I 'route' this through the cloud functions? The only thing I can see happening is using /setCustomClaims, but I can't even add permissions for all projects by user because of the 1000 byte limit. Right now, if someone copies the link to the storage file, anyone can download it, provided they're logged in, regardless of their project level permissions. Are you suggesting somehow I create my own download url using cloud functions and then download the file from storage in the function and re-deliver it (still doesn't seem to protect the storage url, although it's now harder to get)?

Comment: Force clients to use a HTTP or callable function to access the data instead of using the product SDKs.  The function can check to see if what they're trying to do is OK.  For example: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/should-i-query-my-firebase-database-directly-or-use-cloud-functions-fbb3cd14118c